# Getting response from Facebook to Android

Tags: android

I am working on book activity App. I have to check whether the user has liked my FaceBook page.
After the user pressed like button and sign in, the contents of the chapters will be opened. For that, I need to know whether the user liked my page and after that I need to open my next activity.
How to get response from FaceBook. I am totally new to android, help me to proceed.

```
Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/"); 
Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
startActivity(launchBrowser);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just use facebook sdk in your app. I am not sure about the option for liking a page available or not in facebook sdk.
You can download facebook sdk from this link

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

Here is one tutorial
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sig